# Which is faster / more efficient - lots of little MySQL queries or one big PHP array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, performance

I have a PHP/MySQL based web application that has internationalization support by way of a MySQL table called `language_strings` with the `string_id`, `lang_id` and `lang_text` fields.

I call the following function when I need to display a string in the selected language:

```php
public function get_lang_string($string_id, $lang_id)
    {
        $db = new Database();
        $sql = sprintf('SELECT lang_string FROM language_strings WHERE lang_id IN (1, %s) AND string_id=%s ORDER BY lang_id DESC LIMIT 1', $db->escape($lang_id, 'int'), $db->escape($string_id, 'int'));
        $row = $db->query_first($sql);

        return $row['lang_string'];
    }
```

This works perfectly but I am concerned that there could be a lot of database queries going on. e.g. the main menu has 5 link texts, all of which call this function.

Would it be faster to load the entire `language_strings` table results for the selected `lang_id` into a PHP array and then call that from the function? Potentially that would be a huge array with much of it redundant but clearly it would be one database query per page load instead of lots.

Can anyone suggest another more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: your query ends in `LIMIT 1`, how big can an array of 1 be?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem That's the code I have at the moment which is only retrieving one at a time, but the function is being called several times. If I queried the table for all the records for a particular lang_id then the array would have 1000 or more records.

Comment: At least for "static" parts of your application like the *Main Menu* I'd suggest you use a cached version of your menu instead of querying the DB. Like `menu.en.html`, `menu.de.html` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK - I did some benchmarking and was surprised to find that putting things into an array rather than using individual queries was, on average, 10-15% SLOWER.

I think the reason for this was because, even if I filtered out the "uncommon" elements, inevitably there was always going to be unused elements as a matter of course.

With the individual queries I am only ever getting out what I need and as the queries are so simple I think I am best sticking with that method.

This works for me, of course in other situations where the individual queries are more complex, I think the method of storing common data in an array would turn out to be more efficient.

Comment: how are you accessing the array in memory? you're not using array_key_exists() anywhere, right? because this function is horribly inefficient

Comment: @talkol Is this true? Sounds ridiculous that testing whether a hash table key exist should be inefficient - it's an operation that is supposed to run in constant time.

Comment: Does your database run on the same machine as the php code (i.e. the webserver)?

Answer (score 8):

There isn't an answer that isn't case sensitive. You can really look at it on a case by case statement. Having said that, the majority of the time, it will be quicker to get all the data in one query, pop it into an array or object and refer to it from there.

The caveat is whether you can pull all your data that you need in one query as quickly as running the five individual ones. That is where the performance of the query itself comes into play.

Sometimes a query that contains a subquery or two will actually be less time efficient than running a few queries individually.

My suggestion is to test it out. Get a query together that gets all the data you need, see how long it takes to execute. Time each of the other five queries and see how long they take combined. If it is almost identical, stick the output into an array and that will be more efficient due to not having to make frequent connections to the database itself.

If however, your combined query takes longer to return data (it might cause a full table scan instead of using indexes for example) then stick to individual ones.

Lastly, if you are going to use the *same* data over and over - an array or object will win hands down *every single time* as accessing it will be much faster than getting it from a database.

Comment: If it was just 5 queries, it wouldn't be an issue. Sometimes there could be 100 or more calls to the get_lang_string function on one page.

Comment: @PandyLegend So run a few tests manually :) More often than not, storing it once and using it from the same place will be quicker, but like I say, there are some cases where it will cause the initial query to be much longer (but these are pretty much test on a case by case basis).

Comment: thanks. I think it will be a case of do some benchmarking and play it by ear. At the moment it's not an issue because the system isn't busy, but I in the future it could be incredibly busy so I have to weigh it all up now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with what everybody says here.. it's all about the numbers.

Some additional tips:

1. Try to create a single memory array which holds the minimum you require. This means removing most of the obvious redundancies.
2. There are standard approaches for these issues in performance critical environments, like using memcached with mysql. It's a bit overkill, but this basically lets you allocate some external memory and cache your queries there. Since you choose how much memory you want to allocate, you can plan it according to how much memory your system has.
3. Just play with the numbers. Try using separate queries (which is the simplest approach) and stress your PHP script (like calling it hundreds of times from the command-line). Measure how much time this takes and see how big the performance loss actually is.. Speaking from my personal experience, I usually cache everything in memory and then one day when the data gets too big, I run out of memory. Then I split everything to separate queries to save memory, and see that the performance impact wasn't that bad in the first place :)

Comment: thanks. Regarding point 1 I think perhaps I could load all the common strings into an array (such as those needed on every page) and then only query individually the uncommon ones.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Fluffeh on this: look into other options at your disposal (joins, subqueries, make sure your indexes reflect the relativity of the data -but don't over index and *test*). Most likely you'll end up with an array at some point, so here's a little performance tip, contrary to what you might expect, stuff like

```
$all = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

is less memory efficient compared too:

```
$all = array();//or $all = []; in php 5.4
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
{
    $all[] = $row['lang_string '];
}
```

What's more: you can check for redundant data while fetching the data.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is to do something in between. Retrieve all strings for a lang_id that are shorter than a certain length (say, 100 characters). Shorter text strings are more likely to be used in multiple places than longer ones. Cache the entries in a static associative array in get_lang_string(). If an item isn't found, then retrieve it through a query.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently at the point in my `site/application` where I have had to put the brakes on and think very carefully about speed. I think these speed tests mentioned should consider the volume of traffic on your server as an important variable that will effect the results. If you are putting data into javascript data structures and processing it on the client machine, the processing time should be more regular. If you are requesting lots of data through mysql via php (for example) this is putting demand on one machine/server rather than spreading it. As your traffic grows you are having to share server resources with many users and I am thinking that this is where getting JavaScript to do more is going to lighten the load on the server. You can also store data in the local machine via `localstorage.setItem(); / localstorage.getItem();` (most browsers have about 5mb of space per domain). If you have data in database that does not change that often then you can store it to client and then just check at 'start-up' if its still in date/valid.

This is my first comment posted after having and using the account for 1 year so I might need to fine tune my rambling - just voicing what im thinking through at present.